# Solana metaplex auction fails in ValidateSafetyDepositBoxV2 instruction with "Supplied an invalid creator index to empty payment account"

Tags: flutter, solana, metaplex

I'm porting metaplex auction-house to Flutter mobile.

When creating auction with instant sale price of 0.1 wrapped sol, I have encountered the following error at the stage of *ValidateSafetyDepositBoxV2* instruction.

The error was "Supplied an invalid creator index to empty payment account" and there is only one point where this message can be printed is Rust's *process_empty_payment_account*().

The most weird thing is that *process_empty_payment_account* function is called only from *EmptyPaymentAccount* instruction and my program didn't call it.

any idea what's happening?

Actual error log:

```
I/flutter ( 2718):  {accounts: null, err: {InstructionError: [0, {Custom: 63}]}, logs: [Program p1exdMJcjVao65QdewkaZRUnU6VPSXhus9n2GzWfh98 invoke [1], Program log: Instruction: Validate Safety Deposit Box V2, Program log: Supplied an invalid creator index to empty payment account, Program p1exdMJcjVao65QdewkaZRUnU6VPSXhus9n2GzWfh98 consumed 11849 of 200000 compute units, Program p1exdMJcjVao65QdewkaZRUnU6VPSXhus9n2GzWfh98 failed: custom program error: 0x3f], unitsConsumed: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why that error was given after deploying a new program with some logs to the rust program. It was that I passed the wrong value for the metadata's address as the 4th account.

```
pub fn process_validate_safety_deposit_box_v2<'a>(
    program_id: &'a Pubkey,
    accounts: &'a [AccountInfo<'a>],
    safety_deposit_config: SafetyDepositConfig,
) -> ProgramResult {
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let safety_deposit_config_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let auction_token_tracker_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let mut auction_manager_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    *let metadata_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;*
....
```

So, the program failed at `Metadata::try_from_slice_checked` and returns error of `InvalidCreatorIndex` at the following code.

```
impl Metadata {
    pub fn from_account_info(a: &AccountInfo) -> Result<Metadata, ProgramError> {
        let md: Metadata =
            try_from_slice_checked(&a.data.borrow_mut(), Key::MetadataV1, MAX_METADATA_LEN)?;
        Ok(md)
    }
}
```

It's a pity that the code didn't give a more elaborate error.